# Android Room: Creating a one-to-one relationship entity

Tags: android, sqlite, entity, android-room

I'm creating a small project with Room and three tables (jobs, tags, categories).

Essentially:

- A job belongs to (or has) 1 and only category, but a job can have 0..N tags.
- A category has 0..N jobs.
- A tag has 0..N jobs.

I'm having some trouble trying to model all the data, especially when it comes to the relationships between the entities. More concretely, I have:

```
fun JobListing.toJobEntityList(): List<JobEntity> {
    val jobEntityList = mutableListOf<JobEntity>()
    this.jobs.take(50).forEach { job: Job ->
        jobEntityList.add(
            JobEntity(
                jobId = job.id,
                title = job.title,
                url = job.url,
                companyName = job.companyName,
                jobType = job.jobType,
                publicationDate = job.publicationDate,
                relocation = job.candidateRequiredLocation,
                salary = job.salary
            )
        )
    }
    return jobEntityList
}
```

This extension function is being called when I'm fetching the data from the network, so I can convert it to entities and store them in my DB.
I'm essentially creating a `JobEntity`, but a job should have 1 category and 0..N tags associated. The problem is that I don't know how to add that data related to the relationship between a job and its category and tags.

This is my `JobEntity` class:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "Jobs",
    indices = [
        Index("id", unique = true)
    ]
)
data class JobEntity(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val jobId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url") val url: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "company_name") val companyName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_type") val jobType: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publication_date") val publicationDate: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "candidate_required_location") val relocation: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salary") val salary: String
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you should model your database like this:

1. Job_Category
2. Tags
3. Jobs (add category_id field and add 1 foreign key referencing to Category table)
4. Job_Tags (add tag_id, job_id fields and add 2 foreign keys referencing to Category and Jobs tables)

[image]

```
@Entity(tableName = "Category")
data class CategoryEntity(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
)

@Entity(tableName = "Tags")
data class TagEntity(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "Jobs",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = CategoryEntity::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["categoryid"])]
)
data class JobEntity(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryid", index = true) val categoryid: Int,
    // ... other fields
)
@Entity(
    tableName = "JobTags",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = TagEntity::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["tagId"]),
        ForeignKey(entity = JobEntity::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["jobId"]),
    ]
)
data class JobTagEntity(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tagId", index = true) val tagId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "jobId", index = true) val jobId: Int,
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! And now the question, with this model of the DB is, how do I properly insert the data that is fetched from the network? Because now my extension method `toJobEntityList` expects to create a `List<JobEntity>` and each `JobEntity` expects a `categoryId` which I don't think I have in that moment

Comment: You should insert firstly categories then tags then jobs and tags.

Comment: If the post was helpful you can accept it as answer

Comment: what about the `id` of the `JobTagEntity`? is it not auto generated? I'm getting a `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)` when inserting in that table

Comment: I forgot it to mark auto generated. But the data is coming from server. If your data model is different from this and does not store tags as an entity you can modify. Delete JobTagEntity and store tags as an array using converter